# Counting several stores in different countries issue

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, I have a table called Stores, with a location identifier that points to another table called "Location", which points to itself as to identify it's own country/city/etc.

I want to count how many stores there are in a certain country but the query just counts how many there are in the same city

The Query is (the issue is in the count section, translation: tienda-store, lugar-location):

```
SELECT ti.nro||' '|| ti.calle   as "Direccion",l.nombre "Ciudad", lu.nombre "Pais", 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tienda tie WHERE tie.fk_lugar = l.id) "Cantidad"

FROM tienda t,THE (SELECT direccion from tienda WHERE tienda.id=t.id) 
ti,lugar l, lugar lu

WHERE t.fk_lugar=l.id and l.tipo='CIUDAD' and 
l.lugar_id=lu.id and lu.tipo = 'PAIS'
```

The result is something like this:

```
Direccion |Ciudad  |Pais  |Cantidad  
 address 4|Miami   |USA   |   1  
 address 3|New York|USA   |   1  
 address 2|Toronto |Canada|   2  
 address 1|Toronto |Canada|   2
```

When it should show:

```
Direccion |Ciudad  |Pais  |Cantidad  
 address 4|Miami   |USA   |   2  
 address 3|New York|USA   |   2 
 address 2|Toronto |Canada|   2  
 address 1|Toronto |Canada|   2
```

I'm assuming it's counting same cities and I can't figure out how to make it count countries instead

[Tienda inserts](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5zGdmYSeP0ASXFfTV9BT0RIMWM)

[Lugar inserts](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Xzn5xWfvhkT3dhT0ZoeUJwT1k)

Comment: can you please show your dataset?

Comment: Edited to add data set pictures @realspirituals

Comment: It would be much better to have the data in text form, and preferably in a format we can reconstruct it. But from those images, should the cantidad value for all USA stores be 3 (from the stores in Chicago, Miami and Dallas), and for all Canada stores it should be 3 (from the three Toronto stores)? And there should be rows for all the other stores?

Comment: Exactly, USA, Canada, Germany, and the UK should have 3 in "Cantidad" whilst the rest (other countries like Belgium, Denmark, etc) should have 1. I'll try adding the create and insert sequences in a moment

Comment: I think what Gordon showed is right then, with `on lc.fk_lugar = lp.id`? Or close anyway, it isn't extracting the object fields the same way.

Comment: Damn, I tried it but apparently inserted the wrong data in its place. It works now! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.direccion, lc.nombre as ciudad, lp.nombre as pais,
       count(*) over (partition by lp.nombre)
from tienda t join
     lugar lc
     on t.fk_lugar = lc.id and lc.tipo = 'CIUDAD' join
     lugar lp
     on lc.?? = lp.id and lp.tipo = 'PAIS';
```

The key idea is the `count(*) over`.  A window function does the count you want.  I am unclear from the question what the right `join` key is for `pais`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear enough. lugar l would point to a city, and lugar lu to a country. So lu.id points to the country's id number. I added data set pictures for more reference

Comment: Added wrong data before, thank you for your answer. It works great now